# Single Logout with OIDC

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am working on an Idp customization. I need to have it handle a Single Logout request from an SP that had logged in with OIDC.
I currently have the Single Logout functionality for SAML, but I the client has requested for OIDC as well. 
Is there a standard industry method of sending a Single Logout request? What does a typical SP send to the Single Logout endpoint?

Answer (score 7):

As [sdoxsee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098564/sdoxsee) mentioned, it is an implementers "Draft" that methods for performing Session management and Logout Methods.

[OpenID Connect Front-Channel Logout](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html) specification defines a **RP-Initiated Logout** mechanism that uses front-channel communication communicate logout requests from the OpenID Connect Provider to Relying Parties via the User-agent. RP-Initiated Logout

OpenID Connect [Back-Channel Logout specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html) defines an **OpenID Connect Provider initiated logout mechanism** that uses direct back-channel Communication between the OpenID Connect Provider and Relying Parties being logged out.

These MAY be used in combination with RP-Initiated Logout which then causes a OpenID Connect Provider initiated logout all of which COULD be caused by the end user.

Answer (score 3):

Logout is out of scope for the oidc spec as far as I know but this is the implementers draft that I've found implemented a number of times for different providers.

https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout

Comment: it is not an RFC, it is a so-called "implementers draft"

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how the request is sent to the endpoint? In what format?

Comment: Updated. Thanks Hans

Comment: TheFootClan, it is a browser redirect to the OP (or authorization server)

Comment: It's just a plain redirect? So I'm assuming the parameters needed sent to the Logout URL are sent as querystring appended to the URL?

Comment: It could be send in querystring if you use `GET` method or url-form-encoded if you use `POST` method. Here more info: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout first § under the param list.